# VM1661:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token s in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

Hi guys there have been an error in my site for quite long and I have searched whole internet for the answers but didn't found any solutions here is my **onsubmit** code

```
onSubmit = () => {
    fetch("http://localhost:2000/signin", {
      method: "post",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        email: this.state.signinEmail,
        password: this.state.signinPassword,
      }),
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then(console.log(this.state.signinEmail, this.state.signinPassword))
      .then((data) => console.log(data));
  };
```

Also i have checked the response of the network tab it says success but getting this error don't know how to get rid of it. I have also checked the solution of the
Stackoverflow that write **Accept:application/json** but still didn't worked,but it gives me "bad request" error
The backend code is:

```
app.post("/signin", (req, res) => {
  if (
    req.body.email === database.users[0].email &&
    req.body.password === database.users[0].password
  ) {
    res.send("success");
  } else {
    res.status(400).json("error logging in");
  }
});
```

I have also tested it through **Postman** it works successfully on it with no errors.
This the json server.
[image]

Comment: Your **response** (`res.send("success");`) is not JSON, so don't try to read it as JSON via `.then((response) => response.json())`. To read the body as text, use `.text()`.

Comment: Since this is a very specific mistake unlikely to be of use to others in the future, I suggest just deleting the question. Happy coding!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This happens when you make a request to the server and parse the response as JSON, but it’s not JSON.

```
fetch('/url').then(res => res.json())
```

The actual request worked fine. It got a response. But the `res.json()` is what failed.

The root cause is that the server returned HTML or some other non-JSON string.

You can try changing `res.json()` to `res.text()`.

```
onSubmit = () => {
    fetch("http://localhost:2000/signin", {
      method: "post",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        email: this.state.signinEmail,
        password: this.state.signinPassword,
      }),
    })
      .then((response) => response.text())
      .then((data) => console.log(data));
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Ayaz, as suggested when I modified the code to

```
.then((response) => response.text())
.then((data) => console.log(data));
```

It helped me to see the response which appeared in the console as a text, it was a redirect to a login page and it was in HTML, hence it was not valid Json.

I solved my problem by adding `[AllowAnnoymous]` to my post method in the controller.

Hopes this helps someone, I was bugged down for hours.